# How to implement Facebook Like feature using Graph api in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-remoteview

I have a requirement to implement Facebook Like feature in my widget application. For that purpose i am trying to implement Facebook LikeView from SDK `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'`. But unfortunately I couldn't use this view because widgets uses RemoteViews. So I am completely stuck with the approach that I should follow to implement **Facebook Like** using `Graph api` since there is a lack of documentation for this purpose. I am posting the code that I am using for Facebook Like as follows

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeView);
        likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
        likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);

        likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
                "https://www.facebook.com/JavaDigest/",
                LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.facebooklike.MainActivity">

    <com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
        android:id="@+id/likeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider2XXXXXXXXXXX85"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Any kind of help and alternate solutions that will be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have also implemented a facebook like feature and it is successfully worked for me with LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH too.

Here is a code with Detail explanation

**Define it in MainActivity**

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
LikeView likeView;
```

**MainActivity onCreate Method**

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeview);

likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.BOX_COUNT);
likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
            "http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/",
             LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);
```

**In your Mainactivity add onActivityResult method**

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <meta-data
     android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
     android:value="@string/FacebookId" />
```

**and Remove provider from manifest**

```
//Remove this provider

<provider
     android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
     android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider2XXXXXXXXXXX85"
     android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: This is working fine with my case as well. But i want to use Graph API.